# Recalculate table price without changing the table name

Tags: sql, case

I have opencart. In the product table is the column `price` I added some extra columns.

I want to fill the price and recalculate them with the extra data when it's > 0 I need to do that in SQL.

This is what I want to do:

```
IF cost_price > 0 AND shipping_cost1 > 0 AND shipping_cost2 > 0 AND margin > 0
THEN price = cost_price + shipping_cost1 + shipping_cost2_margin
ELSE price = price
```

As far as I can find I could do that with `CASE`. But with `CASE` I need to change `price` to `retail_price`. I need to keep it `price`

My thought on the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer,
    (SELECT price = CASE
        WHEN cost_price > 0 AND shipping_cost >0 AND shipping_cost1 >0 AND margin >0
        THEN ((cost_price * margin) + shipping_cost + shipping_cost1 )
        ELSE (price) FROM product_d.........
```

Original query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer,
    (SELECT price FROM product_d...........
```

Who can help or give tips for better coding?

Comment: What is exactly your question? Did you try to run your query? Did you debug it? Does your query produce an error?

Comment: I ran the query. The price doesn't change. Also isn't changing when editing the given changes from chue X

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the second `SELECT` statement to fix the syntax for the `CASE`. It should look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer,
    (SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN cost_price > 0 AND shipping_cost >0 AND shipping_cost1 >0 AND margin >0
        THEN ((cost_price * margin) + shipping_cost + shipping_cost1 )
        ELSE (price)
    END AS price
    FROM product_d.........
```

This part of your original query:

```
SELECT price = CASE
```

changed to

```
SELECT CASE
```

Also, the second to last line was added:

```
END AS price
```

The added line above closes the `CASE` statement, and also gives the resulting column the name `price`.

Comment: Price stays the same. Doesn't fill with the price i need.

Comment: I have this:***  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT CASE WHEN cost_price = 0 AND shipping_cost =0 AND shipping_cost1 =0 AND margin =0 THEN ((cost_price + margin) + shipping_cost + shipping_cost1 )ELSE (price) END AS price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd*** This doesn't do it. When I do this:***    'price'            => ($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price'] * $query->row['margin']),
*** in the array, price changes.  @peterm